# How do I use hgsubversionbranch with this non-standard layout?

Tags: hgsubversion

I have a pretty non-standard SVN repo layout:

```
http://svn.my.company.corp/<area>/trunk/<project>
http://svn.my.company.corp/<area>/branches/<person>/<project>
http://svn.my.company.corp/<area>/tags/<project>/<tag>
```

I'm not terribly worried about the tags as they're not really in use that much. But I'm trying to get the branches to work correctly.

Currently I have an `.hgrc` containing the following:

```
[hgsubversionbranch]
default = trunk/MyProject
wayne = branches/WaynesWorld/MyProject
```

and I run the following command:

```
> hg clone --layout custom --startrev 15042 svn+https://svn.my.company.corp/myarea/ MyProject
```

(using the `--startrev` because I have a lot of irrelevant revisions) but when it "finishes" cloning it says it can't find anything.

This is a pretty new change effectively starting [here](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/commits/91d061989acc2e92a3796186c3224b69c1c178b), so I haven't been able to find much information aside from the docs, which don't seem to address my particular circumstance.

What am I doing wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. Have you managed to make it work?

Comment: @MirceaNistor It's been a long time and I've since left that company (and finished yet another one yesterday). I know that at one point I just used hg for my local development and only pushed to SVN when I had to deploy. I even convinced the other guy in my area to use it with me, so we pulled changes from each other. Would've used a network drive, but there are issues with that :(